# parasoft C++ - Skipped

Tags: c++, misra, parasoft

I am use to Parasoft C++test, I want to perform static analysis of a code. The code is developed in C++ in `Windriver VxWorks` Diab.
For Configuring Projects for Testing, I use the following :
For direct testing of Wind River projects, choose Use Options from Wind River 
Workbench project. 
And For custom projects (projects not managed by  Workbench), you can try to use the Use options from a build system option, which is based on the same mechanism as Use options from `Wind River Workbench` project.

But not at run time code analysis for example Misra-c++

```
Total Files: 1
Source Files to Check: 1
Total Source Lines: 56
Source Lines to Check: 56
Excluded Files: --

Files Checked (Coding Standards): 0/0    Skipped: 1
Failed Runs: 0
Violations Found: 0
Violations Suppressed: 0
Number of Rules Violated: 0
```

What is the reason?

Comment: I would kindly suggest you should remove the question as it refers to proprietary software.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's wrong with questions that refer to proprietary software?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. The question isn't a good one though. It is not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
Must clean project and after the test run.